# Displaying records where the same value have been mentioned more than 3 times in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, record

How can I find a value that has been mentioned several times in a row.

```
ID |1_Jan|3_Jan|4_Jan|4_Jan|
12 |  2  |  3  |  2  |  4  |
31 |  3  |  4  |  3  |  1  |
25 |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |
26 |  3  |  3  |  3  |  3  |
```

In the case of this table, I want to get out ID 25 and 26 because here the values 1 and 3 have been used 3 or more times in a record.

I was also wondering how can I for example only get out ID 25 even if 26 also has 3 or more?

Comment: Consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

One way is to unpivot and aggregate:

```
select id, val, count(*)
from ((select id, 1_jan as val from t) union all
      (select id, 2_jan as val from t) union all
      (select id, 3_jan as val from t) union all
      (select id, 4_jan as val from t) 
     ) t
group by id, val
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I see now that I forgot a part in the text. How can I get out only ID 25 even if 26 also have value that have been displayed 3 or more times?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows with all equal column values, and then order by common column value:

```
with cte as (select t.id, t.1_Jan r, (t.1_Jan = t.2_Jan) and (t.2_Jan = t.3_Jan) and (t.3_Jan = t.4_Jan) val from test_table t)
select c.id from cte c where c.val = 1 order by c.r limit 1;
```

Output:

| id |
| --- |
| 25 |

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2945182811350345b2c7fe5019e1133).